# Kendo ui grid date field, updates day before

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I have seen [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/format-date-in-grid) on "Wannes" comment and it´s exactly what it´s happening to me, but i don´t know how to resolve it because i don´t understand the problem. What i have is a simple grid working with CRUD.

The grid is a client table, whenever one wants to add a new client, he hits the new button and a popover appears. In this popover there are many fields, two of them are:

**DataCriacao** (the date when the client was created)

**DataUpdate** (the date when the client was updated)

This is my grid initialization code:

```
var dataSource  = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: 
        {
          read:  
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php",        
            },

          update: 
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php?type=update",
              type:"POST",
              complete: function (e) 
              {
                $("#gridClientes").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
              } 
            },
          destroy: 
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php?type=destroy",
              type: "POST"
            },
          create: 
            {
              url: "data/clientes.php?type=create",
              type: "POST",
              complete: function (e) 
              {
                $("#gridClientes").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
              }
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) 
            {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) 
                {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            }                      
        },
        error:function(e)
        {
          console.log(e);
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 8,
        schema: 
        {
            data: "data",
            total: function(response) 
            {
              return $(response.data).length;
            },
            model: 
            {
              id: "idCliente",
              fields: 
              {
                **(other fields here)**
                NomeUtilizadorCriador: {editable: false,validation: { required: false } },
                DataCriacao: {type:"date",   editable: false},
                NomeUtilizadorUpdate: {editable: false, validation: { required: false } },
                DataUpdate: {type:"date",   editable: false},
              }
            }
        }
      });
      $("#gridClientes").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: dataSource,            
          pageable: 
          {
           messages: 
           {
            display: "{0} - {1} / {2} items", 
            empty: "0 items",
            page: "Page",
            of: "of {0}", //{0} is total amount of pages
            itemsPerPage: "items per page",
            first: "Go to the first page",
            previous: "Go to the previous page",
            next: "Go to the next page",
            last: "Go to the last page",
            refresh: "Refresh"
            }
          },
          serverPaging: true,
          height: 550,
          toolbar:[{name: "create",text: $varGridQuartosBtnNovoPT},{name: "close",text: "X"}],
          columns: [  
                  **(other fields here)**
                  { field: "NomeUtilizadorCriador", title: "Criado por", hidden: true},
                  { field: "DataCriacao", title: "Criado em",format:"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", hidden: true, width: "10px"},
                  { field: "NomeUtilizadorUpdate", title: "Atualizado por", hidden: true},
                  { field: "DataUpdate", title: "Atualizado em",format:"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", hidden: true, width: "10px"},
                  {command:[{ text: "Detalhes", click: showDetails },{ name: "edit",text:
                  {edit:$varGridQuartosBtnEditarPT,update:$varGridQuartosBtnActualizarPT,cancel:$varGridQuartosBtnCancelarPT}},
                  { name: "destroy",text:$varGridQuartosBtnApagarPT }],title:"&nbsp;",width: "30px"}],

          editable: {
            mode:"popup",

            template:kendo.template($("#popupGridClientes").html())

          }
```

So, for example if i wanted to create a new client today, this is what appears in those two fields:

**DataCriacao: Wed Apr 22 2015 10:46:02 GMT+0100 (WEST)** (creation date)

**DataUpdate: Wed Apr 22 2015 10:46:02 GMT+0100 (WEST)** (update date)

Now if i want to update the client information, the problem appears:

**DataUpdate: Wed Apr 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (WEST)** (update date)

These two fields are type DATE on my database. I don´t know what to do because i don´t understand where to start, does [this](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/08/11/how-to-force-hack-kendo-ui-grid-to-display-the-correct-date/) helps?.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but as you said, you store data in database in DATE format. That's why time part is zero in your example.
Check what data is in your database. It shouldn't have time.
Problem is in your backend/database side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, in my database i have: 2015-04-22. It doesn´t have time and never had the time inserted, i really don´t understand. I think i have to do something in the "parameterMap" and also in the "parse " function, but i don´t know how.

Comment: But your database column can't hold time with date values (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

Comment: But i don´t want the time. so in that logic, what it is showing in the database is correct, the problem appears when i´m updating(client-side) where it shows me the time.

Comment: Please, explain detailed what is your problem

Comment: Hi suvroc, thanks for trying to help me, but my problem is well explained in the last part of my question. Setp 1: you insert a client and the date format in client side is-Wed Apr 23 2015 10:46:02 GMT+0100 (WEST), in my database appears 2015-04-23 which is correct i think. The problem is when i update the client, step 2:Wed Apr 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (WEST) ( the time is not correct, but i don´t want the time!), in my database appears 2015-04-22...why the day comes back? it should update with the today date.

Comment: Ok, I am understand now. Check Update request (what date is inside), then check timezone of date value on your backend and timezone configuration in db. Especially check if you use the same tz in all places.

Comment: Thanks suvroc...i´m going to see and then i´ll post here